# String variable not behaving correctly in json.dumps

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I've got an API request I am sending and I gather the necessary data and compile it in the proper format into a string called compiled_string. When I try to include it in json.dumps, it is being changed so that my API request is not working properly.

```
print(compiled_string) #Below is how the string is structured for reference
#{"uuid1": {"uuid2": 1.0,"uuid3": 123.0}, "uuid4": {"moreuuids": 2.3}}

#This payload works in the API request if I paste the exact value of compiled_string
payload = json.dumps({
"field1": "value1"
"name" : "funtimes"
"required_data" : {"uuid1": {"uuid2": 1.0,"uuid3": 123.0}, "uuid4": {"moreuuids": 2.3}}
})


#This doesn't work in the API request using the string variable which should contain the exact same data as above
payload_with_variable = json.dumps({
"field1": "value1"
"name" : "funtimes"
"required_data" : compiled_string})

#When debugging I notice escape slashes are added before each double quote and a pair of double quotes are added to the beginning and end of the string as well
#"{\"uuid1\": {\"uuid2\": 1.0,\"uuid3\": 123.0}, \"uuid4\": {\"moreuuids\": 2.3}}"}
```

Should I be trying to adjust the string to make it look like the original string so it can work properly or is there another way to resolve this? I've string some string manipulation but that still didn't appear to work unless I didn't do it correctly. I tried .replace on the payload to remove backslashes but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Since its a string, it remains a string in the dumped json. Presumably, the api wants the dict, not a string? I'm not sure what you mean  by "compiled string" in the first place. Was it a dict that had its own `dumps`? If so, don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compiled_string` is a JSON string, not a dictionary. But the value of `required_data` should be a dictionary. So you need to parse the JSON to convert it to a dictionary.

```
payload_with_variable = json.dumps({
    "field1": "value1"
    "name" : "funtimes"
    "required_data" : json.loads(compiled_string)})
```

Comment: That did it! Just so I understand, when you say "dump the JSON" that's unrelated to the json.dumps method, but means getting rid of the JSON for compiled_string to have it as a dictionary right? Appreciate the quick response, thank you so much!

Comment: I meant to say you need to parse the JSON.